# Vue.JS failed to dynamically load template

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I can't manage to build something similar to the vue.js example router application (https://github.com/chrisvfritz/vue-2.0-simple-routing-example).

I have removed every fancy stuff in order to make it work. But I still have the infamous error message on page load:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <Anonymous>
       <Root>
```

I did nothing fancy, just trying to dynamically load a page:

```
// file: app/index.js
import Vue from 'vue';

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
  },
  computed: {
    ViewComponent() {
      const matchingView = 'Home';

      return require('./pages/' + matchingView + '.vue');
    },
  },
  render(h) {
    return h(this.ViewComponent);
  },
});
```

And the page is only a static template:

```
// file app/pages/Home.vue
<template>
  <p>Home Page</p>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
  };
</script>
```

What I don't understand is that I can make my page work if I statically import my page:

```
// file app/index.js
import HomePage from './pages/Home.vue';

const app = new Vue({
  // ...
  computed: {
    ViewComponent() {
      return HomePage;
    }
  }
});
```

I suspect that I did not correctly configured my webpack build, but can't find out what is happening here... I have installed the vue-loader and vue-template-compiler as stated in the documentation, but it did not change anything.

Here are my dependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "vue-loader": "^13.0.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.2",
    "webpack": "^3.4.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.6.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.4.2"
  }
```

And the webpack.config.json file

```
var path = require('path');


module.exports = {
  entry: './app/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'app.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'vue-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.test$/,
        exclude: '/node_modules/',
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
    }
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
  },
};
```

Comment: it worked in webpackbin without any error... https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KqhO-poNk7irR0szpHc

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. It seems that I messed up my webpack.config.js somewhere.. But it is very similar to the one used in the Vue.js routing example. And this one works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't directly answer your question but if your just interested in trying out vue use vue-cli to make a simple app.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#CLI
https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/
It's the easiest way to start out with vue.